# URL Rewrite, Web Farm, and ASP.NET MVC 3: The virtual path 'null' maps to another application, which is not allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, web-farm

For reference: Scott Guthrie's [Microsoft Web Farm entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/08/introducing-the-microsoft-web-farm-framework.aspx).

Using Microsoft Web Farm, you put a "URL Rewrite" to direct inbound traffic to the web farm.  Using ASP.NET MVC 3, I get the following error:

`The virtual path 'null' maps to another application, which is not allowed.`

Take out the URL Rewrite, and the site fires up without issues.  In this case, I have the Controller and the Primary on the same server, which Scott Guthrie says in his post will work.

I cannot move the URL Rewrite to the site level because it doesn't work that way for a web farm.  Maybe I should move the sites to a different tcp port like 8080?

EDIT:

I got part of this to work.  I NATTED the outside traffic to come in to port 591 on the server, then had the URL Rewrite go to the server farm, which is on port 80.  I needed to separate the Controller traffic from the Primary traffic.  Will keep you posted.

The only bad part is that each day I check it, I get a 502 error.  I reboot the Controller / Primary server and it works like a charm, until the next day.

Comment: Hi Zim, I've met the same problem as yours, have you found a cause and solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

add a web on 80 port

add real web on 81 port

create farm

edit arr

add a condition {SERVER_PORT} = 80

so,80 rewrite to farm and 81 not

about 502,may edit the proxy timeout(default:30) larger than web timeout(default:120)